# Where are the three secrets where you have to throw a book?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

In [The Mysterious Library](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/maps/1509995-the-mysterious-library-adventure-map-100-downloads), it is mentioned that there are three places where you have to throw a book to unlock something.

Where are they?

Comment: Regarding the tag:  It explicitly states in the tag wiki: "Questions about custom maps...fall under this tag."

Comment: @WillB (see above)

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts as an answer so I'll just comment: in the link above that you gave, there is a walk through. Perhaps it will show you where to throw the books.

Answer (score -1):

This youtuber did a walk-through and I think he tells you where to throw the books

Click 'Watch in youtube' - The youtube icon

That is a series consisting of 8 videos, you should be able so see them from the sidebar.

Fast-forward the video and you should find where to throw.

Otherwise if you don't feel like watching the videos, just simply use some X-ray mods to find hoppers or such items. If you don't mind hacking. You could use some other mods too but the x-ray was the only one that came to mind.

Comment: Can you edit your question into having the solution in it? Generally answers that are only on video or other external sources are frowned upon (But you can still refer to the video) in Stack Exchange =)

Comment: Sorry about the video, it was the only resource that I could find, I decided to help him/her out so I added my only thing that I knew. I will now download the map and hack it. Sorry,  I had to hack for the anwser.